# Как в C# заменить " кавычки на « »

Tags: c#, строки, замена

Есть строка:

```
ООО "Парус"
```

Как заменить в ней кавычки типа `"` на кавычки типа `»` и `«` соответственно?

Comment: например с помощью регулярного выражения

Comment: А как быть с порядком?

Comment: С каким порядком?

Comment: @Radzhab какая разница порядка если регуляркой находим вхождения и заменяем на символы... то есть, грубо говоря, регулярка будет типа `("(\w+)")+` Это слишком утрированно и потом будет заменить на `«$2»`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

По идее, нужно заменять кавычки, которые стоят перед словами на открывающие, а после слов - на закрывающие. Что-то вроде этого (возможно, можно упростить код):

```
var s = "ООО \"Парус\" и ООО \"НПП \"Рога и копыта\"";
var s2 = Regex.Replace(s, "\"(\\w+)", "«$1");
var s3 = Regex.Replace(s2, "(\\w+)\"", "$1»");
Console.WriteLine(s3);
```

Comment: А как быть в случае ООО "Научно-производственное предприятие "ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ"

Comment: @Radzhab, а чем ООО "НПП "Рога и копыта" отличаются? Будет работать.

Comment: Изумительно!!!!!!

Comment: `ООО "Парус" и ООО "НПП "Рога и копыта""` - последняя кавычка не заменяется

Comment: @Grundy, так нельзя писать. Кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются. К тому же данное выражение работает в тепличных условиях (с пробелами между словами, без знаков препинаний в кавычках и т.п.). Все остальное нужно дорабатывать при появлении новых условий.

Comment: @Vlad. да, возможно

Comment: Я извиняюсь конечно,со всеми строками пашет - кроме как ООО "ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ ОФИСНЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ (СОФТ)"  . Мб скобка мешает?

Comment: @Radzhab, ну да. Второе выражение можно дополнить `(\\w+|\\))\"`

Comment: @Vlad, кто сказал, что так нельзя писать?

Comment: @ixSci, [грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/89-kav)

Comment: @Vlad, всё правильно. Для русскго языка использования `"` вообще не должно быть, а текст `ООО "Парус" и ООО "НПП "Рога и копыта""` должен быть превращён в `ООО «Парус» и ООО «НПП „Рога и копыта”»`, поэтому, всё там может быть. Просто автор не понимает ещё этого. Ну или ему повезёт, и таких вариантов он не встретит.

Comment: @ixSci, он не _должен_ _быть_ превращен в то, что вы предлагаете. Он _может_ _быть_ превращен в это. Процитирую: "Если внутри слов, заключенных в кавычки, встречаются другие слова, в свою очередь заключенные в кавычки, рекомендуется (при условии, что для этого есть технические возможности) использовать кавычки разного рисунка: внешние – «елочки», внутренние – „лапки” (или – в текстах, набранных на компьютере, – "компьютерные кавычки") . Если же такой возможности нет, то закрывающие кавычки ставятся только один раз. Кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются".

Comment: @Vlad, интересная у Вас интерпретация написанного. Вы понимаете, что `ООО "Парус" и ООО "НПП "Рога и копыта"` уже не правильно, уже не по правилам языка, в котором должны использоваться ёлочки? Так вот, приняв во внимание, что исходный текст в любом случае плюёт на правила написания в русском языке, почему мы должны считать, что и другое правило языка не будет нарушено?

Comment: @ixSci, исходная строка написана по правилам русского языка. Рекомендуется использовать кавычки разного рисунка, а если нет технической возможности это сделать, то закрывающая кавычка ставится только один раз. Т.е. такое написание допустимо (вероятно, не было технической возможности использовать иной способ), а значит не противоречит правилам русского языка.

Answer (score 9):

Для решения можно воспользоваться [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Для получения нужной части строки, которую надо заменить, можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение

```
"(.+?)"
```

В этом случае текст *между* кавычками будет сохранен в первой группе.

При простой замене кавычек можно использовать перегрузку со строкой:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(source, "\"(.+?)\"", "«$1»")
```

Если нужны какие-то дополнительные операции, можно воспользоваться перегрузкой принимающей MatchEvaluator:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(source, "\"(.+?)\"", m =>
{
    return $"«{m.Groups[1]}»";
});
```

Comment: А как быть в случае если название такое ООО "Научно-производственное предприятие "ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ"

Comment: @Radzhab, искать другое регулярное выражение

Comment: @Radzhab, Если такие варианты у Вас могут быть, то у Вас большие проблемы.

Comment: @Radzhab, вложенность только одно кратная может быть? или не ограничено? и на одном уровне может быть несколько групп с кавычками?

Comment: Вложенность может быть в два элемента, но хорошо было бы понять как для бесконечного тоже сделать

Comment: @Radzhab, в два элемента это как в примере `ООО "Научно-производственное предприятие "ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ"` или что-то вроде `ООО "Научно-производственное предприятие "ГАРАНТ-"СЕРВИС"-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ"`?

Comment: @Radzhab, может ли быть несколько кавычек на одном уровне, например: `ООО "Парус" и ОАО "Рога и копыта"`?

Answer (score 3):

Вот еще один вариант:

```
string res = Regex.Replace("ООО \"Парус\" и ОАО \"Рога и копыта\"", 
                        "\"(\\w[\\w ]*\\w)\"", @"«$1»");

MessageBox.Show(res, "Результат", MessageBoxButtons.OK,   MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Это способ с более строгими условиями поиска, попробуйте несколько вариантов:

- `"\"(\\w[\\w ]*\\w)\""` - названия фирм могут включать в себя буквы и цифры (класс символов "\w"), и состоять из нескольких слов (конструкция `"[\\w ]*"`)
- `"\"(\\a[\\a ]*\\a)\""` - этот шаблон аналогичен предыдущему, но в отличии от первого не допускает наличия в названиях фирм цифр (`"\\a"`).
- `"\"(\\p{IsCyrillic}[\\p{IsCyrillic} ]*\\p{IsCyrillic})\""` - названия фирм могут быть только на кириллице (`"\\p{IsCyrillic}"`).

Можете также попробовать использовать такой класс символов `"\\p{Lu}"` он задает множество заглавных букв.

Однако, иногда возникают ситуации требующие нетривиального подхода, например в подобной ситуации:

```
ООО "Научно-производственное предприятие "ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ"
```

Регулярные выражения "из коробки" практически не применимы, однозначного решения для подобных ситуаций не существует. Решение иногда все удается найти, например можно ограничит размер подстроки с названием фирмы использовав квантор {n,м}, он означает что предыдущий элемент должен повторяется как минимум n раз, но не более чем m раз. И добавить более точные признаки указывающие на начала искомого фрагмента, в данном случае это конечный набор слов указывающих на тип юр. лица ("ООО", "ОАО", "ЗАО" и т.д.).

А вложенные кавычкам внутри названия можно выделить простым паттерном `"\s«\w"`. Вот примера такого кода:

```
 string src = 
   "ООО \"Парус\" и ОАО \"Рога и копыта\" при согдействии "+
   "ООО \"Научно-производственное предприятие "+
   "\"ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТ бла бла бл\" ";
 string res = Regex.Replace(src, "(ООО/ЗАО/ОАО]\s]9", @"$1«");
 res = Regex.Replace(res, "\"(\\w[\\w \\-«]*\\w)\"", @"«$1»");
 MessageBox.Show(res, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
   MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

источник: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_classes

Comment: А как быть в случае если название такое ООО "Научно-производственное предприятие "ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ"

Comment: Хорошо бы заменить регулярки на *verbatim-string-literal* для уменьшения экранирующих слэшей.

Comment: Тире внутри названия фирмы решается просто, его просто добавляем к множеству допустимых символов внутри названия фирмы:

Comment: О уважаемый  Radzhab, вы нашли самое слабое место регулярных выражений, в ситуации когда внутри названия присутствует не парная кавычка одними регулярками уже ничего не сделать

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант решения подобной задачи.

```
    var input = "ООО \"Парус\"и ОАО \"НПП \"Рога и копыта\"\"";
    var openQuote = "«";
    var closeQuote = "»";
    var quotationMark = "\"";

    // Шаг 1. Замена кавычек в которые заключено целое слово.
    input = Regex.Replace(input, "\"(\\w+)\"", openQuote + "$1" + closeQuote );
    
    // Шаг 2. Замена кавычек в которые заключено несколько слов 
    // (разделенных пробелом, запятой, точкой, или любым другим символом).
    if (input.Contains(simpleQuote))
      input = Regex.Replace(input, "\"(.+)\"", openQuote + "$1" + closeQuote );
    
    // Шаг 3. Замена оставшихся кавычек. Есть есть символ буквы справа от кавычки ", 
    // то замена на «; если слева, то на ».
    if (input.Contains(simpleQuote))
    {
      input = Regex.Replace(input, "\"(\\w+)", openQuote + "$1");
      input = Regex.Replace(input, "(\\w+)\"", "$1" + closeQuote );
    }

    // Результат: ООО «Парус»и ОАО «НПП «Рога и копыта»»
```

Answer (score 0):

Как самый простой вариант: перед открывающей кавычкой внутри текста всегда должен стоять пробел, соответственно

```
string st = "ООО \"Парус\" и ОАО \"НПП \"Рога и копыта\"";   
string new_st = st.Replace(" \"", " «");
```

Затем проверить первый символ в строке, и если это кавычка, то тоже заменить на открывающую елочку.
После этого все остальные кавычки заменять на закрывающие елочки.

```
if (new_st.StartsWith("\"")) new_st = string.Concat("«", new_st.AsSpan(1));
new_st = new_st.Replace("\"", "»");

//было: "ООО "Парус" и ОАО "НПП "Рога и копыта" 
//стало: «ООО «Парус» и ОАО «НПП «Рога и копыта»
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю многословной, но более устойчивый чем на регулярках вариант (C# 10):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace gmafffff.excel.udf.Text;

public sealed class ПреобразовательКавычек {
    private СимволыКавычек _символыКавычек;

    public ПреобразовательКавычек(char кавычкаНаЗамену = '"',
                                  (char Левая, char Правая)? кавычкиВнешние = null,
                                  (char Левая, char Правая)? кавычкиВнутренние = null) {
        _символыКавычек = new СимволыКавычек(кавычкаНаЗамену, кавычкиВнешние, кавычкиВнутренние);
    }

    public string КавычкиЕлочки(string текст) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(текст)) return "";
        _символыКавычек = new СимволыКавычек(кавычкиВнутренние: СимволыКавычек.КавычкиВнешниеПоУмолчанию);
        return new Парсер(текст, _символыКавычек).ToString();
    }

    public string КавычкиЕлочкиИЛапки(string текст) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(текст)) return "";
        return new Парсер(текст, _символыКавычек).ToString();
    }

    private sealed class Парсер {
        private readonly string текст;
        private readonly List<Токен> Токены = new();
        private bool КавычкиСбалансированы = true;
        private Range остатокТекста;

        public Парсер(string текст, СимволыКавычек символыКавычек) {
            this.текст = текст;

            РазобратьТекст(текст, символыКавычек);
            if (Токены.Count > 0)
                ПрисвоитьУровни();
        }

        private void РазобратьТекст(string текст, СимволыКавычек символыКавычек) {
            var кавычкаЛи = (char символ) => символыКавычек.Кавычки.Contains(символ);

            var токенНачало = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < текст.Length; i++) {
                var последнийСимволЛи = i == текст.Length - 1;

                if (!последнийСимволЛи && !кавычкаЛи(текст[i])) continue;
                if (последнийСимволЛи && !кавычкаЛи(текст[i])) {
                    остатокТекста = Range.StartAt(токенНачало);
                    break;
                }

                var токенКонец = кавычкаЛи(текст[i]) ? i : i + 1;
                var диапазон   = токенНачало .. токенКонец;

                var токен = new Токен(new Кавычка(символыКавычек, текст[i]),
                                      new КонтекстКавычки(текст, i),
                                      диапазон);
                Токены.Add(токен);
                токенНачало = i + 1;
            }

            if (Токены.Count % 2 != 0)
                КавычкиСбалансированы = false;
        }

        private void ПрисвоитьУровни() {
            const int начальныйУровень = 1;

            var уровеньСлева  = начальныйУровень - 1;
            var уровеньСправа = начальныйУровень - 1;

            int i = 0,
                j = Токены.Count - 1;

            do {
                i = ОбходСлева(i);
                j = ОбходСправа(j);
                if (Токены[i].ТипКавычки != Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен
                 && Токены[j].ТипКавычки != Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен) return;

                // Рассчитываем баланс открывающих — закрывающих кавычек
                var неопределённыеТокены = Токены.ToArray()[i .. (j + 1)];
                var балансОпределённыхКавычек = неопределённыеТокены
                                               .Where(токен => токен.ТипКавычки != Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен)
                                               .Aggregate(0,
                                                          (баланс, токен) =>
                                                              токен.ТипКавычки == Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая
                                                                  ? ++баланс
                                                                  : --баланс);
                var дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек = уровеньСлева - уровеньСправа + балансОпределённыхКавычек;
                var свободныхКавычек = неопределённыеТокены.Count(т => т.ТипКавычки == Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен);
                var остатокСвободныхКавычек = свободныхКавычек > Math.Abs(дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек)
                                                  ? свободныхКавычек - Math.Abs(дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек)
                                                  : 0;
                if (Math.Abs(остатокСвободныхКавычек) % 2 != 0) КавычкиСбалансированы = false;

                if (!КавычкиСбалансированы) {
                    // Количество открывающих — закрывающих кавычек не сбалансировано,
                    // нужный тип кавычки достоверно установить нельзя, значит будем гадать.
                    // В названиях организаций преобладают открывающие кавычки, поэтому предпочитаем их.
                    if (уровеньСправа > 0 || свободныхКавычек >= 1)
                        Токены[i].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
                    else
                        Токены[i].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;

                    continue;
                }

                ПопробуйРаскидатьОстаток(i, дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек, остатокСвободныхКавычек);
            } while (Токены.Any(т => т.Уровень is null));


            /// <summary> Присваивает уровень тексту в кавычках слева направо </summary> 
            /// <return> Последний необработанный индекс </return>
            int ОбходСлева(int стартовыйИндекс) {
                for (var i = стартовыйИндекс; i < Токены.Count; i++) {
                    if (Токены[i].Уровень is not null) {   // Уровень уже присвоен
                        if (уровеньСлева != уровеньСправа) // Но баланса уровней нет
                            КавычкиСбалансированы = false;
                        return Токены.Count - 1;
                    }

                    if (Токены[i].ТипКавычки is Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая) {
                        Токены[i].Уровень = ++уровеньСлева;
                    }
                    else if (Токены[i].ТипКавычки is Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая) {
                        Токены[i].Уровень = уровеньСлева--;
                    }
                    else if (i == 0 || уровеньСлева == 0) { // Смотрим слева. Если начало строки или 0 уровень
                        уровеньСлева         = начальныйУровень;
                        Токены[i].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
                        Токены[i].Уровень    = уровеньСлева;
                    }
                    else if (КавычкиСбалансированы
                          && i + 1 < Токены.Count
                          && Токены[i + 1].Уровень is { } следующийУровень) {
                        if (уровеньСлева < следующийУровень) {
                            Токены[i].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
                            Токены[i].Уровень    = ++уровеньСлева;
                        }
                        else if (уровеньСлева >= следующийУровень) {
                            Токены[i].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;
                            Токены[i].Уровень    = уровеньСлева--;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return i;
                    }

                    if (уровеньСлева < 0) {
                        КавычкиСбалансированы = false;
                        уровеньСлева          = 0;
                    }
                }

                return Токены.Count - 1;
            }

            /// <summary> Присваивает уровень тексту в кавычках справа налево </summary> 
            /// <return> Последний необработанный индекс справа </return>
            int ОбходСправа(int стартовыйИндекс) {
                for (var j = стартовыйИндекс; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (Токены[j].Уровень is not null) {   // Уровень уже присвоен
                        if (уровеньСлева != уровеньСправа) // Но баланса уровней нет
                            КавычкиСбалансированы = false;
                        return 0;
                    }

                    if (Токены[j].ТипКавычки is Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая) {
                        Токены[j].Уровень = ++уровеньСправа;
                    }
                    else if (Токены[j].ТипКавычки is Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая) {
                        Токены[j].Уровень = уровеньСправа--;
                    }
                    else if (j == Токены.Count - 1 || уровеньСправа == 0) {
                        // Смотрим справа. Если конец строки или 0 уровень 
                        уровеньСправа        = начальныйУровень;
                        Токены[j].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;
                        Токены[j].Уровень    = уровеньСправа;
                    }
                    else if (КавычкиСбалансированы
                          && j - 1 >= 0
                          && Токены[j - 1].Уровень is { } предыдущийУровень) {
                        if (предыдущийУровень <= уровеньСправа) {
                            Токены[j].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
                            Токены[j].Уровень    = уровеньСправа--;
                        }
                        else if (предыдущийУровень > уровеньСправа) {
                            Токены[j].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;
                            Токены[j].Уровень    = ++уровеньСправа;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return j;
                    }

                    if (уровеньСправа < 0) {
                        КавычкиСбалансированы = false;
                        уровеньСправа         = 0;
                    }
                }

                return Токены.Count - 1;
            }

            /// <summary> Пытается определить кавычку по уровню её вложенности </summary>
            void ПопробуйРаскидатьОстаток(int index,
                                          int дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек,
                                          int остатокСвободныхКавычек) {
                var нужноОткрывающихКавычек = дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек < 0 ? -дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек : 0;
                var нужноЗакрывающихКавычек = дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек > 0 ? +дисбалансОткрывающихКавычек : 0;

                if (нужноОткрывающихКавычек + остатокСвободныхКавычек == 0) {
                    Токены[index].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;
                    нужноЗакрывающихКавычек--;
                }
                else if (нужноЗакрывающихКавычек + остатокСвободныхКавычек == 0) {
                    Токены[index].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
                    нужноОткрывающихКавычек--;
                }

                if (уровеньСлева >= 1
                 && нужноЗакрывающихКавычек + остатокСвободныхКавычек > 0) {
                    Токены[index].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;
                    нужноЗакрывающихКавычек--;
                }

                if (Токены[index].ТипКавычки == Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен)
                    Токены[index].ТипКавычки = Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            var строитель = new StringBuilder(текст.Length);
            foreach (var т in Токены) {
                строитель.Append(текст[т.Диапазон]);
                строитель.Append(т.Кавычка.ДайСимволКавычки(т.Уровень ?? 0, т.ТипКавычки));
            }

            строитель.Append(текст[остатокТекста]);
            return строитель.ToString();
        }
    }

    private sealed record Токен(Кавычка Кавычка, КонтекстКавычки Контекст, Range Диапазон) {
        private Кавычка.ТипКавычки? _типКавычки;
        public int? Уровень;

        public Кавычка.ТипКавычки ТипКавычки {
            get => _типКавычки ?? РасчетныйТипКавычки();
            set => _типКавычки = value;
        }

        public Кавычка.ТипКавычки РасчетныйТипКавычки() {
            if (Кавычка.Тип is not Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен) return Кавычка.Тип;
            if (ВероятноОткрывающаяКавычкаЛи()) return Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Открывающая;
            if (ВероятноЗакрывающаяКавычкаЛи()) return Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Закрывающая;
            return Кавычка.ТипКавычки.Неизвестен;
        }

        public bool ВероятноЗакрывающаяКавычкаЛи() {
            return Контекст switch {
                { СимволДо   : null } or { СимволНепробельныйДо   : null } => false,
                { СимволПосле: null } or { СимволНепробельныйПосле: null } => true,

                { СимволДо: { } до, СимволПосле: { } после } when char.IsWhiteSpace(после)
                                                               && (char.IsLetterOrDigit(до) // "текст текст» текст"
                                                                || до is '!' or '?' or '…') =>
                    true, // "текст текст!» текст"
                { СимволНепробельныйДо: { } доНепробел, СимволНепробельныйПосле: { } послеНепробел }
                    when char.IsLetterOrDigit(доНепробел)
                      && (char.IsSeparator(послеНепробел) // текст » \nтекст
                       || char.GetUnicodeCategory(послеНепробел) is
                              UnicodeCategory.ClosePunctuation       // текст » ) текст
                           or UnicodeCategory.OtherPunctuation       // текст » ! текст
                           or UnicodeCategory.FinalQuotePunctuation) // текст » ” текст
                    => true,
                _ => false
            };
        }

        public bool ВероятноОткрывающаяКавычкаЛи() {
            return Контекст switch {
                { СимволДо   : null } or { СимволНепробельныйДо   : null } => true,
                { СимволПосле: null } or { СимволНепробельныйПосле: null } => false,
                { СимволДо: { } до, СимволПосле: { } после } when char.IsLetterOrDigit(после)
                                                               && (char.IsWhiteSpace(до) // текст «текст
                                                                || (char.IsLower(до)
                                                                 && char.IsUpper(после))) // текст«Текст
                    => true,
                { СимволНепробельныйДо: { } доНеПробел, СимволНепробельныйПосле: { } послеНеПробел }
                    when
                    char.IsLetterOrDigit(послеНеПробел)
                 && (char.IsSeparator(доНеПробел) // текст\n « текст
                  || char.GetUnicodeCategory(доНеПробел) is
                         UnicodeCategory.OpenPunctuation         // текст ( « текст
                      or UnicodeCategory.InitialQuotePunctuation // текст “ « текст 
                    )
                    => true,
                _ => false
            };
        }
    }

    private sealed record КонтекстКавычки(string Текст, int ПозицияКавычки) {
        public ReadOnlySpan<char> ТекстДо => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Текст)
                                                 ? ReadOnlySpan<char>.Empty
                                                 : Текст.AsSpan(0, ПозицияКавычки);

        public ReadOnlySpan<char> ТекстПосле => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Текст)
                                                    ? ReadOnlySpan<char>.Empty
                                                    : Текст.AsSpan(ПозицияКавычки + 1,
                                                                   Текст.Length - (ПозицияКавычки + 1));

        public char? СимволДо => ТекстДо.IsEmpty ? null : ТекстДо[^1];
        public char? СимволПосле => ТекстПосле.IsEmpty ? null : ТекстПосле[0];

        public char? СимволНепробельныйДо {
            get {
                for (var i = ТекстДо.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (char.GetUnicodeCategory(ТекстДо[i]) != UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator)
                        return ТекстДо[i];
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        public char? СимволНепробельныйПосле {
            get {
                for (var i = 0; i < ТекстПосле.Length; i++) {
                    if (char.GetUnicodeCategory(ТекстПосле[i]) != UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator)
                        return ТекстПосле[i];
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed record Кавычка(СимволыКавычек СимволыКавычек, char СимволКавычки) {
        public enum ТипКавычки {
            Неизвестен,
            Открывающая,
            Закрывающая
        }

        public enum УровеньКавычки {
            Неизвестен,
            Внешняя,
            Внутренняя
        }

        public ТипКавычки Тип => СимволыКавычек.НовыеКавычкиОткрывающие.Contains(СимволКавычки)
                                     ? ТипКавычки.Открывающая
                                     : СимволыКавычек.НовыеКавычкиЗакрывающие.Contains(СимволКавычки)
                                         ? ТипКавычки.Закрывающая
                                         : ТипКавычки.Неизвестен;

        public УровеньКавычки Уровень => Тип switch {
            ТипКавычки.Открывающая when СимволКавычки == СимволыКавычек.ОткрывающаяВнешняя => УровеньКавычки.Внешняя,
            ТипКавычки.Открывающая when СимволКавычки == СимволыКавычек.ОткрывающаяВнутренняя => УровеньКавычки
               .Внутренняя,
            ТипКавычки.Закрывающая when СимволКавычки == СимволыКавычек.ЗакрывающаяВнешняя => УровеньКавычки.Внешняя,
            ТипКавычки.Закрывающая when СимволКавычки == СимволыКавычек.ЗакрывающаяВнутренняя => УровеньКавычки
               .Внутренняя,
            _ => УровеньКавычки.Неизвестен
        };

        public char ДайСимволКавычки(int уровеньПоУмолчанию = 0,
                                     ТипКавычки типПоУмолчанию = ТипКавычки.Открывающая) {
            if (Тип != ТипКавычки.Неизвестен && Уровень != УровеньКавычки.Неизвестен)
                return СимволКавычки;


            var тип = Тип == ТипКавычки.Неизвестен
                          ? типПоУмолчанию
                          : Тип;

            var место = Уровень == УровеньКавычки.Неизвестен
                            ? уровеньПоУмолчанию % 2 == 1 ? УровеньКавычки.Внешняя : УровеньКавычки.Внутренняя
                            : Уровень;

            return (тип, место) switch {
                (ТипКавычки.Открывающая, УровеньКавычки.Внешняя)    => СимволыКавычек.ОткрывающаяВнешняя,
                (ТипКавычки.Открывающая, УровеньКавычки.Внутренняя) => СимволыКавычек.ОткрывающаяВнутренняя,
                (ТипКавычки.Закрывающая, УровеньКавычки.Внешняя)    => СимволыКавычек.ЗакрывающаяВнешняя,
                (ТипКавычки.Закрывающая, УровеньКавычки.Внутренняя) => СимволыКавычек.ЗакрывающаяВнутренняя
            };
        }
    }

    private sealed record СимволыКавычек {
        public static readonly (char Левая, char Правая) КавычкиВнешниеПоУмолчанию = ('«', '»');
        public static readonly (char Левая, char Правая) КавычкиВнутренниеПоУмолчанию = ('„', '“');
        public readonly char ЗакрывающаяВнешняя;
        public readonly char ЗакрывающаяВнутренняя;
        public readonly char[] Кавычки;

        public readonly char Неопределенная;
        public readonly char[] НовыеКавычки;

        public readonly char[] НовыеКавычкиЗакрывающие;
        public readonly char[] НовыеКавычкиОткрывающие;
        public readonly char ОткрывающаяВнешняя;
        public readonly char ОткрывающаяВнутренняя;


        public СимволыКавычек(char неопределенная = '"',
                              (char Левая, char Правая)? кавычкиВнешние = null,
                              (char Левая, char Правая)? кавычкиВнутренние = null) {
            кавычкиВнешние    ??= КавычкиВнешниеПоУмолчанию;
            кавычкиВнутренние ??= КавычкиВнутренниеПоУмолчанию;

            Неопределенная        = неопределенная;
            ОткрывающаяВнешняя    = кавычкиВнешние.Value.Левая;
            ЗакрывающаяВнешняя    = кавычкиВнешние.Value.Правая;
            ОткрывающаяВнутренняя = кавычкиВнутренние.Value.Левая;
            ЗакрывающаяВнутренняя = кавычкиВнутренние.Value.Правая;

            НовыеКавычкиОткрывающие = new[] { ОткрывающаяВнешняя, ОткрывающаяВнутренняя };
            НовыеКавычкиЗакрывающие = new[] { ЗакрывающаяВнешняя, ЗакрывающаяВнутренняя };
            НовыеКавычки            = НовыеКавычкиОткрывающие.Concat(НовыеКавычкиЗакрывающие).ToArray();
            Кавычки                 = НовыеКавычки.Append(Неопределенная).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Поддерживаемые сценарии можно увидеть в тестах (C# 11):

```c#
using FluentAssertions;
using gmafffff.excel.udf.Text;

namespace udf.tests;

public class ПреобразовательКавычекТесты {
    [Theory]
    // краевые случаи
    [InlineData(null, "")]
    [InlineData("текст", "текст")]
    //позиционное определение
    [InlineData(@"  ""…текст…""  ", "  «…текст…»  ")]
    [InlineData(@"  ""   текст   ""  ", "  «   текст   »  ")]
    // пробельные символы
    [InlineData(@""" текст  ""текст текст""", "« текст  «текст текст»")]
    [InlineData("\" текст\n\"текст текст\"", "« текст\n«текст текст»")]
    [InlineData(@""" текст текст""  текст""", "« текст текст»  текст»")]
    [InlineData("\" текст текст\"\nтекст\"", "« текст текст»\nтекст»")]
    // знаки препинания
    [InlineData(@""" текст текст!"" текст""", "« текст текст!» текст»")]
    [InlineData(@""" текст текст "" ! текст""", "« текст текст » ! текст»")]
    //скобки и кавычки
    [InlineData(@"""текст (""текст текст""", "«текст («текст текст»")]
    [InlineData(@"""текст текст"") текст""", "«текст текст») текст»")]
    [InlineData(@"""текст “""текст текст""", "«текст “«текст текст»")]
    [InlineData(@"""текст текст""” текст""", "«текст текст»” текст»")]
    //регистр символов
    [InlineData(@""" текст""Текст текст""", "« текст«Текст текст»")]
    //Название организации
    [InlineData(@"ООО ""Санаторий ""Большой корабль ""Быстрый""", "ООО «Санаторий «Большой корабль «Быстрый»")]
    [InlineData(@"ООО""Санаторий""Большой корабль""Быстрый""", "ООО«Санаторий«Большой корабль«Быстрый»")]
    [InlineData(@"ООО""САНАТОРИЙ""Лазурный""", "ООО«САНАТОРИЙ«Лазурный»")]
    [InlineData(@"ООО""НПП""ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ""", "ООО«НПП«ГАРАНТ-СЕРВИС-УНИВЕРСИТЕТ»")]
    [InlineData(@"ООО""ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ ОФИСНЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ (СОФТ)""", "ООО«ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЕ ОФИСНЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ (СОФТ)»")]
    [InlineData(@"ООО""Парус"" и ООО""НПП""Рога и копыта""", "ООО«Парус» и ООО«НПП«Рога и копыта»")]
    //Спорный момент
    [InlineData(@"""текст""текст2""", "«текст«текст2»")]
    public void ПреобразуютсяКавычкиБезВложений(string text, string result) {
        new ПреобразовательКавычек().КавычкиЕлочки(text).Should().Be(result);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("""""ООО"Парус"и ООО"НПП"Рога и копыта"".""""",
                "ООО«Парус»и ООО«НПП„Рога и копыта“».")]
    [InlineData("""текст "текст "текст"" текст "текст" текст""",
                "текст «текст „текст“» текст «текст» текст")]
    [InlineData(""""текст1 "текст2 „тт3", „тт4" "тт5 «ттт6""" "„тт7", "тт8" "тт9 «ттт10" "»т11"""",
                "текст1 «текст2 „тт3“, „тт4“ „тт5 «ттт6»“» «„тт7“, „тт8“ „тт9 «ттт10» “»т11")]
    [InlineData(""""""1т "„2тт", „3тт", "4тт — "levelUP""", "„6тт", "7тт", "8тт «9ттт""» 00т"""""",
                "1т «„2тт“, „3тт“, „4тт — «levelUP»“», «„6тт“, „7тт“, „8тт «9ттт»“» 00т")]
    // Пример отсюда: https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2835228.html
    [InlineData("""
                "здравствуйте "елочки" менять на "лапки" естественно просто, а как менять наоборот,
                они ведь разные « и », то есть "открывающиеся" и "закрывающиеся", спс"
                """,
                """
                «здравствуйте „елочки“ менять на „лапки“ естественно просто, а как менять наоборот,
                они ведь разные « и », то есть „открывающиеся“ и „закрывающиеся“, спс»
                """)]
    public void ПреобразуютсяКавычкиВложенные(string text, string result) {
        new ПреобразовательКавычек().КавычкиЕлочкиИЛапки(text).Should().Be(result);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("""""ООО"Парус"и ООО"НПП"Рога и копыта"".""""",
                "ООО\\Парус/и ООО\\НПП|Рога и копыта!/.")]
    public void ДругойРисунокКавычек(string text, string result) {
        new ПреобразовательКавычек(кавычкиВнешние: ('\\', '/'), кавычкиВнутренние: ('|', '!'))
           .КавычкиЕлочкиИЛапки(text).Should().Be(result);
    }
}
```

Слабое место — функция `ПопробуйРаскидатьОстаток`, которая получает управление, когда по окружению кавычки невозможно понять какой рисунок у неё должен быть.

Comment: Ничего себе, почти 1С