Енумы кирилицей для удобаства в C#
Нормально ли будет с точки зрения стандартов, перечисления именовать кирилицей для удобства если локализация приложения планируется только на русском. Например я могу написать так:
    enum SelectEnum1
    {
        Вариант1,
        Вариант2
    }
    ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
    box.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SelectEnum1));

Что будет в принципе максимально просто. Но будут ли на меня ругаться?
Или лучше сделать что-то вроде этого:
    enum SelectEnum
    {
        Variant1,
        Variant2
    }
    class EnumView<T> where T : Enum
    {
        public EnumView(T item, string name)
        {
            Item = item;
            Name = name;
        }
        public T Item { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }  

     ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
     box.ItemsSource  = new List<EnumView<SelectEnum>>() {
         new EnumView<SelectEnum>(SelectEnum.Variant1, "Вариант1"),
         new EnumView<SelectEnum>(SelectEnum.Variant2, "Вариант2")};

Но тогда возрастает количество кода во много раз, плюс нельзя сделать биндинг напрямую с моделью или сложно.
Я счтитаю что мой вопрос не имеет ничего общено с этим вопросом Как изменить .ToString() в Enum
Так как суть впороса заключается в допустимости использования кирилических символов в именовании enum. Вопрос же по ссылке эту тему никак не затрагивает.

Нет, так делать не стоит. 1. C# это всеж зарубежный язык, в котором все на английском языке, и все это следует конкретным правилам именования, как гласным, так и нет. Когда в вашем коде часть на английском, а часть на русском, это просто неудобно, это путает, а если у вас в команде человек, который не понимает русский, то ваш код вовсе принесет только боль и страдания. Поэтому, принято писать код всеж на едином, английском языке. 2. Вы путаете параметры и данные. "Вариант" это всеж не "перечисление", а данные, причем динамичные данные, которые не должны быть "захардкожены" в коде.

Что касается "тогда возрастает количество кода" - это значит только одно вы делаете что-то не то, используете то, что не предназначено для вашей задачи. Допустим, зачем вам enum, если можно сделать класс с константами, где название константы будет на английском, а значение русское? Весь ваш код тогда заменится на простое Variant.First, что даст условный "Вариант 1". Ну а если посмотрите на это все повнимательней, то "Вариант" это вовсе "число", 1,2,3,4,5...100...100000, и тут как видите, опять возвращаемся к тому, что вы используете не по назначению enum. Живите проще, пишите проще)

майкрософт по этому поводу возражений не имеет, т.е. в язык введена поддержка юникода, в том числе поддержка юникода и в нейминге [именовании] программы, частей программы, переменных и прочего - тоже есть; а вот стоит ли использовать нейминг не на английском - это вопрос конкретных соглашений внутри компаний и так далее

Пользователю нужно вывести Вариант 1 - с пробелом. Так что...

вместо enum-ов - сделайте массив строк, зачем enum-ы?

@Alexander Petrov или нужно вывести "1. Что то" - с начальными цифрами могут возникнуть проблемы

Похоже на какую-то ерунду, enum сам умеет себя именовать, nameof

@evo Приведите пожалуйста пример как это можно использовать в моем случае?

Переоткрывать бессмысленно, так как использовать или не использовать кириллицу - чисто субъективный вопрос. И уже обсуждалось, кстати: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1545921/240512 У нас в одном проекте используются названия свойств на русском, особого удобства это не добавляет, ибо для полноценной локализации все равно нужен специальный механизм, чтобы были возможны пробелы, знаки препинания и т.п. Смотрите в сторону второго способа.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1571980/373567 кстати вот, 1С#
